# DerivedState inside SideEffect does not cause recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

In the scenario where I need to handle side effect and I need to pass firstItemVisibleIndex is bigger than 0 to the lambda function in the composable. Imagine I have this derivedState

```
val isFirstItemVisible by remember {
   derivedStateOf {
    state.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 
 }
}
```

if I pass this state inside DisposableEffect works well but in DisposableEffect I do not need to clear anything or do something onDispose function. Documentation says that If you will not do anything on onDispose function use SideEffect. When I use SideEffect, isFirstItemVisible value only changed one time. When I go down, it becomes false and when we are on top, we expect it to be true but this value does not get changed because recomposition does not occur. Since recomposition does not occur, block of code inside SideEffect does not run. Why is that happening ?

Comment: Use LaunchedEffect(isFirstItemVisible)

Comment: But I do not need CoroutineScope

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with

```
val isFirstItemVisible by remember (state) {
    state.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 
}
```

thus, the calculation of the `isFirstItemVisible` will occur only if the `state` was changed